# mysql database is not working in xampp 1.8.3

Tags: php, mysql, database, xampp

i am using xampp 1.8.3 on windows 7. when i restart mysql from xampp control panel. it shows

> 1:33:10 PM  [mysql]   Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly. 1:33:10 PM 
>   [mysql]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies,
>   1:33:10 PM  [mysql]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by
>   another method.  1:33:10 PM  [mysql]  Press the Logs button to view
>   error logs and check  1:33:10 PM  [mysql]     the Windows Event Viewer
>   for more clues  1:33:10 PM  [mysql]   If you need more help, copy and
>   post this  1:33:10 PM  [mysql]    entire log window on the forums

then i delete xampp/mysql/data/ibdata1 file and mysql starts.but my database tables have dropped already and i can only view database name with no tables. if i want to remove database i got

> *#1010 - Error dropping database (can't rmdir '.\key', errno: 41).*

every time i have to create new database for run my program.please help.

Comment: The error seems to be self explanatory. Add exceptions to your firewall for port: 3306 (default for MySQL).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I uninstall xampp setup and also removed all the files from `xampp` directory. Please be sure to make a copy of xampp/htdocs folder to store your existing files. Also copy mysql/data folder contents, Since all databases are stored in that folder. After that I re-install xampp setup and restart my PC and now everything is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Windows include a firewall which specifically blocks ports. If you plan on using MySQL through a network port then you should open and create an exception for this port before performing the installation. To check and if necessary add an exception to the firewall settings:

First ensure that you are logged in as an Administrator or a user with Administrator privileges.

1. Go to the Control Panel, and double click the Windows Firewall icon.
2. Choose the Allow a program through Windows Firewall option and click
   the Add port button.
3. Enter MySQL into the Name text box and **3306** (or the port of your
   choice) into the Port number text box.
4. Also ensure that the TCP protocol radio button is selected.
5. If you wish, you can also limit access to the MySQL server by
   choosing the Change scope button.
6. Confirm your choices by clicking the OK button.

Additionally, when running the MySQL Installation Wizard on Windows 7 or newer, ensure that you are logged in as a user with administrative rights.

You can read further here:

- [Installing MySQL on Microsoft Windows](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/windows-using-installer.html)
- [Connecting to MySQL Remotely from Windows with SSH](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/windows-and-ssh.html)

Comment: my windows firewall is already turn off.so i don't think it is the real problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is common issue we are facing during installation of xampp.
Simple solution check installed port then check in service list there is one service running named ***mysqld*** , you have to find it and kill it.  and restart mysql.
Now you will find mysql start running.
Let me know if still you facing any issue.